Odd column table on LaTeX
I'm trying to reproduce this table, but I have a little problem.

What I tried :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.2cm}|}
  \hline
  A & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin (100 \cdot \pi \cdot t)$ & B & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin \left(100 \cdot \pi \cdot t - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ & C & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin \left(100 \cdot \pi \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$  \\ 
  \hline
  D & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin(100 \cdot t)$ & E & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin \left(100 \cdot \pi \cdot t - \pi\right)$ & &
\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}

The result :


You can use the nicematrix package.
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccc}[hvlines,corners=SE] % except south-east corner
  A & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin (100 \cdot \pi \cdot t)$ & B & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin \left(100 \cdot \pi \cdot t - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ & C & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin \left(100 \cdot \pi \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$  \\ 
  D & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin(100 \cdot t)$ & E & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin \left(100 \cdot \pi \cdot t - \pi\right)$ & &
\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


Just remove the & of the empty column to remove the vertical lines (or use \multicolumn{2}{c}{} to explicitly have one empty cell without vertical lines spanning the two columns) and use \cline instead of \hline to limit the length of the horizontal line:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.2cm}|}
  \hline
  A & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin (100 \cdot \pi \cdot t)$ & B & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin \left(100 \cdot \pi \cdot t - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ & C & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin \left(100 \cdot \pi \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$  \\ 
  \hline
  D & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin(100 \cdot t)$ & E & $10^{-2} \cdot \sin \left(100 \cdot \pi \cdot t - \pi\right)$
\\
  \cline{1-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


